# Format Input Type Text without changing the Value

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to format the text value of an Input element without actually changing the value itself. For example, if I am entering an id number of the following format:

```
19801010-1234
```

I wish the value to be 198010101234 but when more than 8 characters are entered, the hyphen should be displayed. I'm using javascript and nodejs.

This is what I currently have:

HTML

```
<input id="ssn"
       className= {styles.input}
       type="input"
       value= {this.format(personalNumber)}
       placeholder={translations.personalNumber}
       onChange={this.onChange} />
```

JS

```
format(value){
    if(value && value.length>8)
        return value.slice(0, 8) + " - " + value.slice(8);
    return value;
}
```

I'm using react and the above will of course change the value itself to include a hyphen which I'm hoping I can avoid.

Comment: So show us what you've already tried

Comment: @Julian Stark Done!

Comment: It's just not possible. If you inspect similar implementations (such as Stack Overflow's tag editor) you'll see they actually display HTML and store the actual value elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" id="num"> <span></span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function formatVal(num) {
        num.length == 8 ? $('#num').val(num+'-') : '';
    };

    function origVal(num) {
        $('span').html(num.replace('-', ''));
    }

    $('#num').keypress(function() {
        formatVal($(this).val());
        origVal($('#num').val());
    });
</script>
```

Might not be the best solution. But it works

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/znr6ycz1/2/)